# PDO Query Update with multi conditions?

Tags: mysql, database, pdo, sql-update

I need your help with a little problem that has caused me to get stuck on that project for 2 days now.

I have a query like this:

```
UPDATE table SET name='$name', surname='$surname'
WHERE cid=$cid AND counter=$count";
```

and I need to write it in PDO syntax. Now, I know how to do it with one condition but I cant get it to work with multi-conditions (like `WHERE cid=$cid AND counter=$count`)

Can someone help me out how to make this work if i have more than one condition on the query?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're looking for [*this*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) (checkout the examples)

Comment: hell yeah, that's it. i needed prepare() instead of query(). thaks Alfasin.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, I think it should work:

```
$query = "UPDATE table SET name='$name', surname='$surname' WHERE cid = :cid AND counter = :counter";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->BindValue(':cid', $cid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->BindValue(':counter', $counter, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Edit: $db is where you call your function to connect to your database.

Comment: Try reading this: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: @YourCommonSense you're not funny at all.

Comment: Thanks @James, although it's an old problem now and I managed to solve it. But it may help others.